# Daily schedule planner

Tags: linux, time-management

I am looking for a **simple** software to plan my (work) day.

At breakfast I want to assign tasks to time slots.

During the day there should be notifications that I am supposed to start a new activity now.

Bonus, if I can track my actual time spent and see a report of this.

It has to run on Linux.

Comment: Does it have to be locally hosted, or would an on-line browser-based system be acceptable? In the latter case, you could use (for example) Google Calendar.

Comment: A browser based solution would be fine. And while a calendar might can be used for my use case I think there might be better solutions out there.

Comment: Have you looked at any software suggested by [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+organizer) or [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+daily+planner)?

Comment: If you have any recommendations feel free to write an answer. Or if you feel my question is misplaced or of low quality please speak your mind. Suggesting to google the question feels affronting.

Comment: I don't use Linux, so I can't speak to the quality of any of the products. However, on other stacks, the querent is expected to have done some research; in this case, I was hoping that this would have been taken as a gentle suggestion to mention any possibilities that you've evaluated, and perhaps indicate why you've rejected them. That was one reason I asked about a web option; for what you described as your needs, Google Calendar works for me (though I interface to it on my 'droid tablet with Appgenix Business Calendar, which is a slightly cleaner interface IMO).

Answer (score 1):

You could use your Mail client, and add a Google Calendar to it. The Google calendar has  "Events" and "Tasks".

The tasks are extended Events having some additional predefined Categories ("Clients", "Anniversary" etc) and also a Status ("Completed" etc).

The interface is similar to user onurcano22's answer.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

From rainlendar.net

> Rainlendar is a customizable calendar application which stays out of
>   your way but keeps all your important events and tasks always visible
>   on your desktop.

It has free and pro versions. It runs on Windows Mac and Linux.

[image: Rainlendar screenshot]